# Angular 8 Tab requires 2 clicks to show the tab active; 1 click gets content, 2nd click sets style

Tags: angular, tabs, ngx-bootstrap

I am working with Angular 8.3. My application uses NgbNav. The html looks like this:

```
<ul ngbNav #projectNav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs">   
  <li [ngbNavItem]="1" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" [disabled]="!projectId">
    <a ngbNavLink [routerLink]="['../..', projectId, 'info']">Project Information</a>   
  </li>   
  <li [ngbNavItem]="2" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" [disabled]="!projectId">
    <a ngbNavLink [routerLink]="['../..', projectId, 'measuresOfProgress']">Measures of Progress</a>   
  </li>   
  <li [ngbNavItem]="3" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" [disabled]="!projectId">
    <a ngbNavLink [routerLink]="['../..', projectId, 'attachment']">Attachments</a>   
  </li>
</ul>
```

When the page displays the first tab is active. Both the tab style and the page content show the tab as active. If I click on the second tab the content loads but the tab style does not change. That is, it appears the first tab is still active and displaying the second tab content. If I click on the second tab again the the tab style changes to show the second tab is active. This same behavior occurs for the third tab. The first tab behaves normally. That is, the tab style changes to active and the first page content is displayed with a single click.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm facing similar kind of issue.

Comment: It's been a while but I recall there was an error in my coding. There were no problems with the framework.